# Passing a numpy function in python to C++ using SWIG directors

Tags: python, c++, arrays, numpy, swig

My code is mainly in C++, but I want to use the SWIG director option to redefine a C++ virtual function in python, and then pass that function back to C++. The following is a simplified example.

Here is my base class in C++ with a virtual function `fun`. `fun` takes in `(double* x, int n)` which allows me to pass a numpy array into it.

```
class base{
public:
    virtual double fun(double* x, int n){return 0.0;}
};
```

I have another class which takes in this base class:

```
class main{
public:
    base* b_;

    main(base& b){
        b_ = &b; 
    }
};
```

This class has a constructor which takes in a base class and stores a pointer to it (`b_`).

I can successfully compile the swig interface into a module named `mymodule` making sure to enable directors (see SWIG interface file below), and, as per the SWIG director documentation, I inherit the base class and redefine the virtual function `fun` as follows:

```
import mymodule
class base(mymodule.base):
    def __init__(self):
        super(base,self).__init__()
    def fun(self,x):
        return x[0]
```

Then I pass it into the `main` class:

```
b = base()
m = mymodule.main(b)
```

However, when I try `m.b_.fun(array([1.,2.]))` I get a `TypeError`:

```
TypeError: 'SwigPyObject' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

Any ideas on how to get this to work? I think when I pass `b` into mymodule.main, C++ is seeing `x` as a double * pointer and doesn't know what to do with it.

By the way, here is my swig interface file:

```
%module(directors="1") mymodule

%{
#define SWIG_FILE_WITH_INIT
/* Includes the header in the wrapper code */
#include "myclasses.h"
%}

%feature("director") base;

%init %{
import_array();
%}

%apply (double* IN_ARRAY1, int DIM1) {(double* x, int n)};

/* Parse the header file to generate wrappers */
%include "myclasses.h"
```

Comment: Does ``b.fun(array([1.,2.])`` work?

Comment: Yes it does. But when I pass `b` into `m` it doesn't.

Comment: @kchow462 If you want any working solution not using swig, I have done things like that using boost.python from C++ to python and again to C++ and even fork and now again to python. It's very tedious to find documentation, but the results and productivity makes my choice of that way. In my recent work django launches zerorpc interfaces from C++ and works fine.

Comment: Thanks Mel. I might have to do this since there doesn't seem to a way of doing this with SWIG, or at least, I don't know of a way.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like an ownership issue from Python.

Provide a hint to SWIG:

```
%new double *fun(double* IN_ARRAY1, int DIM1) {(double* x, int n)};
```

Notice the pointer to the function itself as well.
The Python module will assign proper ownership of the object(s) when %new is used. That's why you can use values but not variables in the call.

Comment: I tried this but it doesn't seem to work. I added the `%new...` statement to my SWIG interface file, but it still gives me the same error. Also, it cannot resolve the fact that the C++ function takes in 2 arguments and the python one takes in 1.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that director isn't recognizing your Python implementation of `fun(double* x, int n)`; it's not doing the overloading of that function.

I suspect that the reason is due to of the fact that your Python implementation uses numpy as argument. Please note that the director will call either the abstract function or the implemented one.

On the other hand, `%apply (double* IN_ARRAY1, int DIM1) {(double* x, int n)}` only declares the typemap logic for wrapping the function in Python, not to the director. Note that this is the reason why `b.fun(array([1.,2.])` works! Said that, you should declare the typemap logic to the director.

Here you can find how to do it:

```
%typemap(directorin,numinputs=1) (double *x, int n)
{
    npy_intp dim = $2;
    $input = PyArray_SimpleNewFromData(1, &dim, NPY_DOUBLE, (void *)$1);
}
```

Hope that this solves your problem and other futures ones :). I got a similar issue and spent few days trying to figure out.